# Create a partition in the table

Tags: oracle

I want to create a table in which data is store in partition as well as sub-partition.

Suppose I want to insert the data under the partition (P_name) of the table. If partition is already exist then insert the data under this partition otherwise create the partition and then insert the data.

Can you please help me on the same problem for sub-partition.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Automatic creation of partitions is supported for interval partitioning only, as of 11.2.

Also, you should generally avoid inserting into particular named partitions.

Comment: Actutally as per project requirement we need to insert the data into particular named partitions

Comment: Do you "insert into my_table partition(partition_name) .."? That is what I mean. The only circumstance I can think of where that is desirable is when performing multiple simultaneous direct path inserts, as it ensures that exclusive locking is applied at the partition level not the table level.

Comment: When you insert data into the table it will automatically be inserted into the correct partition -- you do not need to name the partition except in special circumstances.